# How to read/write to HDFS from the driver in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I'd like to know whether it is possible to access the HDFS from the driver in a Spark application. That means, how to read/write a file from/to HDFS in the driver program. One possible solution is to read a file as a RDD (`sc.textFile`) and then collect it in the driver. However, this is not I'm looking for.

Comment: Collecting the RDD is exactly how one would do that. Any reason you're against it?

Comment: You mean there is no other way? If I go with this approach, how can I write it to hdfs after collecting?

Comment: There's [`RDD.saveAsTextFile()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions), but I'm confused as to why you'd want to collect anything to the driver just to write it back out. Spark expects to perform a series of *transformations* on an RDD before performing an *action*. You generally shouldn't have to bring the data back to the driver unless your goal is just to look at it.

Comment: ok, but my question is any way to access hdfs without going to RDD?

Comment: Please use meaningful [tag:pyspark] + [tag:scala] is not useful because it tells us nothing about the language you use.

Comment: Have you tried webhdfs rest api and/or HDFS FileSystem Java API?

Comment: @satish: I'm coding in Pyspark, so using JAVA API is not feasible. Can I use webhdfs in pyspark?

Comment: @H.Z. WebHDFS is simple rest api. You should be able to use python rest client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access directly HDFS from the driver you can simply do (in Scala):

```
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
```

Then you can use the so created variable `hdfs` to access directly HDFS as a file system without using Spark.

(In the code snapshot I assumed you have a `SparkContext` called `sc` properly configured)

Comment: I just tried this in Spark 1.6 and 2.1:

        val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
        val hdfs = FileSystem.get(sparkConf.hadoopConfiguration)

The result is 'Cannot resolve symbol hadoopConfiguration.

Comment: Hmm, but streamingContext.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration works fine, :)

Comment: that doesn't work because you're trying to get `hadoopConfiguration` from a `SparkConf` object and not form a `SparkContext` object as you should do..

Comment: I see it now. :) Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Simply collect all data at driver with collect action and use java api of hdfs to write it on hdfs.